# Highcharts column click position

Tags: javascript, highcharts, click

Having problem getting Y coordinates, when clicked to column in highcharts.
ChartY is a large number, when I try to click to column.
But this value is correct, when I click above the column.

```
this.update({
    y: event.chartY
})
```

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/falcon4fun/c5pzm/1/)

- Try to ctrl+click above the column on chart, i.e. to Y=100. We will get bar with Y=100.
- Try to ctrl+click to another column, the value of Y will be ~200-400. Why?

Why do `this.y` and `chartY` show me the wrong click value?
How correctly update value and decrease column?
How to solve this problem without logic: **delete this column, insert new column with right value**, because I will have more keybindings and clicks.

Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is value in pixels not value, you need to transform vale by chart.yAxis[0].toValue(event.chartY);

Comment: Thank you very much! As always the solution is simple : ))))